# What data is sent to the target URL when using fetch with credentials set to include

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to understand what information is sent to the target URL when making a fetch request with credentials set to include like so:

fetch(url, {credentials:include})

How does the server behind the target URL know to decode the credentials to validate authentication? I understand this may vary from scenario to scenario but trying to get a general understanding of the concept.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same way it does for any other request.  Typically by parsing a cookie.

Comment: Does that mean the only field that is included/omitted based on my "credentials" settings is the cookie header?

Comment: Yes.  See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials